# Proof that an abelian group whose action has one orbit has a singleton stabiliser.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group acting on some finite set $X$, and suppose that the action of $G$ on $X$ has only one orbit. Show that $|G| = |X|$.

This is my attempted solution, but I am not sure whether it's correct:

Let the action be denoted by $~\widehat{\phantom x} : G \to S_X$, where $\widehat{\phantom x}: g\mapsto \widehat{g}$.

The orbit-stabiliser theorem gives us $|G| = |X| \cdot |\mathrm{Stab}(x)|$, so all we need to show is that $|\mathrm{Stab}(x)| = 1$. Trivially, we have the identity $e\in \mathrm{Stab}(x)$, since $\widehat e = \mathsf{id}$, so $\widehat e (x) = x$. Now suppose $g \in \mathrm{Stab}(x)$, and $g \neq e$. Thus we have $\widehat g(x) = x$. Since $\mathrm{Orb}(x) = X$, then for any $y \in X$, there exists $h \in G$ such that $\widehat h(x) = y$. Now

$$\widehat g(x) = x \\ \implies \widehat h \circ \widehat g (x) = \widehat h (x) \\ \implies \widehat {hg} (x) = \widehat h (x)\\  \implies \widehat {gh} (x) = \widehat h (x) \\ \implies \widehat g(y) = y$$

But we chose $y$ arbitrarily, thus $\widehat g(y) = y$ for all $y\in X$, and since $\widehat g \in S_X$, we have that $\widehat g = \mathsf{id}$, that is, $g = e$ , a contradiction.

I appreciate any feedback.

---

**Edit**:  In the question, the action $\,\widehat{\phantom x}\,$ is *faithful* in order to justify the last step: $\widehat g = \mathsf{id} \implies g = e$.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I don't see what limits the size of $G$ in the original problem statement. For instance, if $X$ has two elements, and $G = H\times \Bbb Z_2$ for some abelian $H$, where $\widehat{(h, n)}$ swaps the two elements of $x$ iff $n = 1$. Why must $H$ be trivial?

Comment: In the current formulation the statement is not true as can be seen by letting $G$ act on the cosets of any non-trivial subgroup.

Comment: I think the original question actually specified that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_X$. Which point of my proof fails in the general case?

Comment: The proof fails in the very last statement: while $\hat{e}=\mathsf{id}$, it is not true that $\hat{g}=\mathsf{id} \Rightarrow g=e$ unless the action is faithful (which it is in the original formulation where $\hat\ :G\hookrightarrow S_X$).

Comment: So if it were known that the G acts faithfully, the question as it stands is correct?

Comment: It is still not true even if you add an assumption that the group action is faithful -- for example $S_3$ acts faithfully on $\{1,2,3\}$, and there is only one orbit, yet $|S_3|\ne|\{1,2,3\}|$.

Comment: It seems that you did not use the abelian property, so the nonabelian counterexample shows the proof cannot work in this case (in fact the stabilizer for 1 in Henning Makholm's example is nontrivial).

Comment: Oh foo, I missed that the group was to be abelian.

Comment: @HenningMakholm So it's true if $G$ is abelian? :)

Comment: Oh wait yeah you did use that $G$ is abelian when doing $gh = hg$ in the 4th step.

Comment: @TobErnack Yes, that's the crux of it in fact.

Answer (score 1):

This is just another way of doing essentially what you did, in (to my mind at least) a slightly more conceptual way.

Since the action of $G$ on $X$ has only one orbit, the stabilisers of any two points in $X$ are conjugate in $G$.  But, since $G$ is abelian, that means that the stabilisers of any two points are, in fact, equal.  This means that any element of $G$ that fixes a point, must actually fix *all* points in $X$, which is to say that it is in the kernel of the action.  However, since the action is faithful, the kernel is trivial, so the point stabilisers are trivial.  Now you can invoke the orbit-stabiliser theorem as in your argument.